# Can I travel to Germany by the last day of my Fiktionsbescheinigung?

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, long-stay-visas, visa-expiration

I have a 3rd country passport and my Fiktionsbescheinigung will expire by the end of 30.11.

Can I travel to Germany on this day without problem?

I had my temporary residence permit for many years before, but due to an urgent issue, I couldn't extend my residence permit in time (I have the Fiktionsbescheinigung until 30.11) in August for my travel to my home country.

In the meantime in November I will contact Ausländerbehörde as well for an appointment by the end of November or early in December if they have slot.

I just want to be sure nothing is bad here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I returned to Germany with Fiktionsbescheinigung, and it was expiring in only the next 3 days without problem.

Comment: I assume this was for an extension of an existing (and still valid when the renewal was applied for) residence permit (Last field checked with: § 81 Abs. 4). Reentry is always allowed. For the first 2 cases (§ 81 Abs. 3) **and** „Gilt nicht für Auslandsreisen“ has been written (or stamped), reentry is not allowed.